# Adding links in "our focus" section in zeriff theme wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, themes

I am using zerif lite theme of WordPress, I wanted to add link to the content of "our focus" section. But when I add abcd  in the content. It shows up as www.website.com/\"link\".

Please help me to show how to add link in "our focus" section.

Comment: This question belongs over in http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you learn how to create a raw HTML link in the format

```
 `<a href="http://www.website.com/special_identifier/"> Click here for more. </a>`
```

Add that code to the text only portion of your post (top tab: Visual <-> Text, use Text).  You also need to make sure in the wp-admin screen that your `Settings --> Permalinks` setup is coherent.  I'd recommend using `(X) Post Name`.